# What does a^b means in swift considering a,b are integers

Tags: swift, xcode

```
print(5^6) // the output is 3
print(10^6) // the output is 12
```

What does the `^` operator do in swift?

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html

Comment: So for your first example binary `0101` xor `0110` is `0011`. And for your second example binary `1010` xor `0110` is `1100`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bitwise XOR operator, which you can find more information about in the [Advanced Operators page](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID33) of the Swift docs.

For `5^6`, it's essentially doing the following:

```
5 = 0x00000101
6 = 0x00000110
    0x00000011 = 3
```

XOR means "exclusive or". In other words, "one or the other but not both". In this case, the "4"-bit is on for both 5 and 6, so that one flips to off. The "1"-bit, and "2"-bit are both only on for the 5 or the 6 respectively, so they stay on.